# ansible playbook variable with double quote

Tags: ansible

How can I add the double-quote between the variable?
eg: **"variable"**

Powershell command:

```
$a = Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "hosts" -and $_.State -eq 'Online'}
        $b = $a.OwnerNode
        Start-VM -Name "hosts" -ComputerName $b
```

My coding:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: hyper-v shutdown vm
      win_shell: |
        $a = Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "{{ hosts }}" -and $_.State -eq 'Online'}
        $b = $a.OwnerNode
        Start-VM -Name "{{ hosts }}" -ComputerName $b
```

Comment: Hi, {{ hosts | quote }} might work, you should give it a try

Comment: not work .....error url: https://upload.cc/i1/2019/08/30/m3iFpz.jpg...    .coding url: https://upload.cc/i1/2019/08/30/m3iFpz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: hyper-v shutdown vm
      win_shell: |
        $a = Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "\"{{ hosts }}\"" -and $_.State -eq 'Online'}
        $b = $a.OwnerNode
        Start-VM -Name "\"{{ hosts }}\"" -ComputerName $b
```

Comment: not OK..........................https://upload.cc/i1/2019/09/02/1IApfm.jpg